# Android - Get ProductFlavor in custom Gradle tasks

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a Gradle Task which is aware of which ProductFlavor is currently being built.

I have the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavorOne {
            // do flavor-specific stuff
        }
        flavorTwo {
            // do other flavor-specific stuff
        }
}

task printFlavor(type: Exec) {
    executable 'echo'
    args 'Building ' + flavorName
}
```

I just need some way of filling in `flavorName`. Setting a project property in the flavor definitions won't do it, because those definitions all get executed every time, so referencing that property won't work because it will always print the last one to be defined.